# entityQuery with multiple conditions on taxonomy terms returns no result

Tags: 8, entities

In my use-case I have an entity which has two fields that reference to unique vocabularies.

News:
 - tag (entity reference)
 - category (entity reference)

If I query on one of those reference I get results however when I query both (an AND filter) I get no results. I have triple-checked it by now and there are entities that contain both the tag and category I am querying.

Is this an user-error or a Drupal bug?

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->condition('type', 'news')
;
$group = $query->andConditionGroup()
    ->condition('field_tag.entity.name', ['cars'], 'IN')
    ->condition('field_category.entity.name', ['sport'], 'IN')
;
$query->condition($group);
$nids = $query->execute();
```

EDIT:
I have found a work-around by querying on the raw value instead of entity.value. This is a non-desirable situation though

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->condition('type', 'news')
;
$group = $query->andConditionGroup()
    ->condition('field_tag.entity.name', ['cars'], 'IN')
    ->condition('field_category', [1], 'IN')
;
$query->condition($group);
$nids = $query->execute();
```

Comment: The default conjunction for EQ is AND(which you can change) so there is nothing wrong with grouping conditions together...that's why it is in there. I don't understand what you have expected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you can't do that is that both of these fields are entity reference to the same entity. That means that the base table is the same base table.

You are asking Drupal to Join the taxonomy_data table to the node table and then make an impossible AND condition on it.

#### P.S.

You can use `condition('field_tags', 1);` instead of `condition('field_tags', [1], 'IN');`

And as mentioned in the comments, the AND condition group is the default, so you don't need to specify it.

#### P.P.S.

You should have both conditions use the referenced id to be consistent.

Comment: This answer only covers a naive imagination of how entity query could work. It's much, much more capable than this, however. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found a hack to this.
here's my explanation of what I've found:

I had 3 fields in my content type each holding a reference to a taxonomy term from different vocabularies.  And I wanted to query the entities for the ones that have a specific taxonomy term in each of those 3 fields (an and condition).

checking the internal SQL query that is produced after several attempts with different combinations of conditions I found that

```
[Previous conditions] AND (taxonomy_term__[taxonomy_term_field_name] IN  (:db_condition_placeholder_2)) AND (taxonomy_term__[taxonomy_term_field_name] IN  (:db_condition_placeholder_3)) AND (taxonomy_term__[taxonomy_term_field_name] IN  (:db_condition_placeholder_4))
```

basically as you can see, it has no reference to the actual individual fields using that specific vocabulary, so my hack is to do something like this:

```
 $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
            ->condition('status', '1')
            ->condition('type', $content_type_machine_name)
            ->condition('field_holding_term_ref.entity.name', array($label_of_term_in_field1, $label_of_term_in_field2, $label_of_term_in_field3), 'IN');
```

again this works, I've tested it and it works as an AND condition returning only content type with those 3 taxonomy terms even if the references to those taxonomy terms are stored in different fields in the content type.

I'm not proud of the hack but it works, so if this can help somebody save sometime, go for it.